# promise with FileReader does not give desired deferred result

Tags: javascript, node.js, promise, es6-promise

After using an file input element I would like upload selected files subsequently. Reading the files with FileReader is asynchronous so I tried to defer the upload function call with a promise. It does not work however as the `vm.upload()` gets called when `vm.files` array is 'not yet filled'. There is no error from the promise by the way.

Why does the promise not 'wait/ defer'? It might be since I should make a promise closer to the async code (in the map method), but I am not sure why?

```
  let filesPromise = inputFiles => {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      inputFiles.filter(file => !this.queue.some(f => file.name === f.name))
        .map(file => {
          file.__size = humanStorageSize(file.size)

          if (this.noThumbnails || !file.type.startsWith('image')) {
            this.queue.push(file)
          }
          else {
            const reader = new FileReader()
            reader.onload = (e) => {
              let img = new Image()
              img.src = e.target.result
              file.__img = img
              this.queue.push(file)
              this.__computeTotalSize()
            }
            reader.readAsDataURL(file)
          }
          return file
        })

      resolve(inputFiles)
      reject(new Error('An error occurred in filesPromise'))
    })
  }

  filesPromise(eventFiles)
    .then(eventFiles => vm.files.concat(eventFiles))
    .then(() => vm.upload())
    .catch(error => console.log('An error occurred: ', error))
```

Comment: reader.onload is async, map doesn't modify

Comment: @baao yeah..., that's it. Any suggestion how to solve this maybe? Make a promise around the reader and have a promise within a promise? I am new to Promises...

Answer (score 0):

As @baao commented, a `map` method containing async code (FileReader event) will just continue and not wait. To solve this the FileReader needs to be put into a Promise and to keep using `map` with Promises one should build an array consisting of Promise-elements. On this array you can subsequently run `Promise.all`. This code works:

```
  let filesReady = [] // List of image load promises
  files = inputFiles.filter(file => !this.queue.some(f => file.name === f.name))
    .map(file => {
      initFile(file)
      file.__size = humanStorageSize(file.size)
      file.__timestamp = new Date().getTime()

      if (this.noThumbnails || !file.type.startsWith('image')) {
        this.queue.push(file)
      }
      else {
        const reader = new FileReader()
        let p = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
          reader.onload = (e) => {
            let img = new Image()
            img.src = e.target.result
            file.__img = img
            this.queue.push(file)
            this.__computeTotalSize()
            resolve(true)
          }
          reader.onerror = (e) => {
            reject(e)
          }
        })

        reader.readAsDataURL(file)
        filesReady.push(p)
      }

      return file
    })

  if (files.length > 0) {
    vm.files = vm.files.concat(files)
    Promise.all(filesReady)
      .then(() => vm.upload())
      .catch(error => console.log('An error occurred: ', error))
  }
```